# What is Entity and EntitySets in RIA Services?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, ria, entityset

I am new to RIA Services and I want to understand Entity and EntitySets in RIA Services

Are "Entity Sets" Tables and Entity a column in the Entity Sets?

Thus Entity Sets having one or more Entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Ria Services object inherit from System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.ClientEntity and they include a bunch of other interfaces like INotifyDataErrorInfo and IChangeTracking. In short if you are using an ORM link EF4 with RIA Services each table would become an 'Entity'.

EntitySet represents a collection of Entity instances. http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ENTITYSET);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

EntitySet's are normally created automatically by Ria and your ORM.

Hope that helps.